# How to restrict the choice of the customer

Tags: php, checkbox

This is an item in my store. Each item can be purchased with five different options. Currently, the user can buy an item with all the possibilities and I want to limit his choice to two out of five. Please give suggestions on how to sink this and can I use `php` or I need to use `JavaScript`.

```
if($check_item_ok[8] == '0') { // 0 for Weapons Pendants
            if($item_exc >= '1') {echo'
                            <div class="opt_title">Increases Mana After monster +Mana/8</div>
                            <div class="opt"><input id="ex1" onclick="checkall();" ame="boxes" value="1" type="checkbox"></div>
            ';};
            if($item_exc >= '2') { echo'
                            <div class="opt_title">Increases Life After monster +Life/8</div>
                            <div class="opt"><input id="ex2" onclick="checkall();" ame="boxes" value="2" type="checkbox"></div>
            ';};
            if($item_exc >= '3') { echo'
                            <div class="opt_title">Increase attacking(wizardly)speed+7</div>
                            <div class="opt"><input id="ex3" onclick="checkall();" ame="boxes" value="3" type="checkbox"></div>
            ';};
            if($item_exc >= '4') { echo'
                            <div class="opt_title">Increase Damage +2%</div>
                            <div class="opt"><input id="ex4" onclick="checkall();" ame="boxes" value="4" type="checkbox"></div>
            ';};
            if($item_exc >= '5') { echo'
                            <div class="opt_title">Increase Damage +level/20</div>
                            <div class="opt"><input id="ex5" onclick="checkall();" ame="boxes" value="5" type="checkbox"></div>
            ';};
            if($item_exc >= '6') { echo'
                            <div class="opt_title">Excellent Damage Rate +10%</div>
                            <div class="opt"><input id="ex6" onclick="checkall();" ame="boxes" value="6" type="checkbox"></div>
            ';};
```

Comment: Define `limit checkbox`

Comment: The user has a choice of six product selection want them fell to two . Generally can select only two of the six choices

Comment: You might was to echo where `$item_exc` equals 1, in which case you should use `==` rather than `>=`

Comment: Now the code sounds like: if `item_exc`=1 -> user has 1 choice, =2 -> user has 2 choices, =3 -> user has 3 choices, etc... What do you want instead?

Comment: users now can select all checkboxs I want to confine myself to two choices of those six . And my question is how to do it?

Comment: i think you need to apply the restriction in javascript, then validate in php. for example, disable the rest of checkboxes after 2 have been selected in js.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to do this on the front-end (i.e. JavaScript) as PHP cannot modify the content after serving the page. You just need to count the checked boxes, and then loop through the inputs setting the disabled property first based on if it is checked, then on whether the maximum has been reached. In the snippet below I just put the logic in your `checkall()` function for convenience (there are better ways, I won't get into). Also you have a typo `ame="boxes"` should be `name="boxes"` .

```js
const checkall = () => {

  const options = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="boxes"]')
  const max_opts = 2
  let sel_opts = 0
  for (const [i, opt] of options.entries()) {
    sel_opts = sel_opts + Number(opt.checked) // + (0||1)
    if (sel_opts === max_opts) // hit max break loop
      break;
  }
  for (const [i, opt] of options.entries()) {
    // only disable the unchecked when max is hit
    opt.disabled = opt.checked ? false : max_opts > sel_opts ? false : true;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="opt_title">Increases Mana After monster +Mana/8</div>
<div class="opt"><input id="ex1" onclick="checkall();" name="boxes" value="1" type="checkbox"></div>
<div class="opt_title">Increases Life After monster +Life/8</div>
<div class="opt"><input id="ex2" onclick="checkall();" name="boxes" value="2" type="checkbox"></div>
<div class="opt_title">Increase attacking(wizardly)speed+7</div>
<div class="opt"><input id="ex3" onclick="checkall();" name="boxes" value="3" type="checkbox"></div>
<div class="opt_title">Increase Damage +2%</div>
<div class="opt"><input id="ex4" onclick="checkall();" name="boxes" value="4" type="checkbox"></div>
<div class="opt_title">Increase Damage +level/20</div>
<div class="opt"><input id="ex5" onclick="checkall();" name="boxes" value="5" type="checkbox"></div>
<div class="opt_title">Excellent Damage Rate +10%</div>
<div class="opt"><input id="ex6" onclick="checkall();" name="boxes" value="6" type="checkbox"></div>
```